# How to find the matrix base change in this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good Morning. I'm trying to solve this exercise: I took the quotient vector space formed by $\operatorname V=\mathbb{R}^5/\langle(3,2,4,-2,5)\rangle$. After starting the vector $x=(3,2,4,-2,5)$ 
I extended by adding more linearly independent  $\mathbb{R}^5$ vectors to form a basis for V.Let be $B_1=\{(1,1,0,0,0),(0,1,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,0,1)\}$ and $B_2=\{(0,0,1,0,1),(1,1,1,0,1),(1,0,1,0,1),(1,-1,2,1,0)\}$ are such bases, note that dimension of $V$ is 4. I have already verified that indeed these sets $B_1$ and $B_2$ are linearly independent and are a set of generators. My biggest question is how to find the matrix base change base to base B1 B2. I have no idea, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mistake is dimension of V is 4.

Let $w=(3,2,4,-2,5)$, $v_1=(1,1,0,0,0)$, $v_2=(0,1,1,0,0)$ ,
$v_3=(0,0,0,1,0)$ and $v_4=(0,0,0,0,1)$ so
$B_1=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$; the same $B_2=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\}$
where

$f_1=(0,0,1,0,1)$,
$f_2=(1,1,1,0,1)$,
$f_3=(1,0,1,0,1)$ and
$f_4=(1,-1,2,1,0)\}$
 so the question is determined the passage
matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$ that is the matrix $P$ who the colons
of matrix $P$ are the expression of $f_i$ in the basis $B_1$
modulo the line $\langle w\rangle$, so for each $f_i, i=1,2,3,4$
we resolve the equation system $x_iw+
f_i=a_iv_1+b_iv_2+c_iv_3+d_iv_4$ we arrive to the solution
$P=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{-3}5 & \frac 25 & \frac{-1}5 & -\frac 75 \\
\frac 15 & \frac 15 & \frac{-3}5 & -\frac 65 \\
\frac 25 & \frac 25 & \frac 45 & \frac{13}5 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -4
\end{array}
\right) $.
good luck

**it is very long to insert this in the comment**

welcome and happy, I explain obtaining the vector $f_1$ and
reasoning in the same way for the other vectors $f_i,i=2,3,4$.

we must solve the system which possesses the augmented matrix
$M_1=:\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3x_1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2x_1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1+4x_1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2x_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1+5x_1
\end{array}
\right) $

so by (by example) Gauss elimination method we obtains  $\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3x_1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -x_1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -2x_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1+5x_1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1+5x_1
\end{array}
\right) $ , so the parameter $x_1$ determine the condition that
the solution exists  modulo $\langle w \rangle $ so $x_1=-\frac 15$ and therefor
$d_1=0$, $c_1=\frac 25$, $b_1=\frac 15$ and $a_1=-\frac 35$.
thanks  and good luck.

with pleasure, I explain you what is the matrix change base: if
$B_1$ and  $B_2$ are
 two bases  of the same vector space $E$, then the matrix change base (passage matrix)
 from $B_1$ to $B_2$ is the matrix $P_{21} $ of operator identity
from $E$ provided with the base $B_2$ in $E$ provided with the
base $B_1$ ie $P_{21} $ is the matrix consisting of colons (in the
order of the basis vectors) representing the expression of $B_2$
vectors in the base $B_1$. Propriety: $P_{12} =P_{21}^{-1} $ is
the  matrix change base  from  $B_2$ to  $B_1$.

application:
 so you have to solve the systems in the  quotient space
$\Bbb{R}^5/\langle w \rangle$, so  really must write ${\bar f_i} =
a_i\bar{v_1}+b_i\bar{v_2}+c_i\bar{v_3}+d_i\bar{v_4}$,  which is
equivalently to solve the system of equations  $x_iw+
f_i=a_iv_1+b_iv_2+c_iv_3+d_iv_4$ in  the original space as the
quotient is done by $\langle w \rangle$ that is in $\Bbb{R}^5$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution , but please Could you explain me more detail the process ?, I really do not understand what the system of equations . Sorry but I think the answer was very direct and I am a beginner in linear algebra. Happy day!

Comment: Please see the detail added in the answer, thanks

Comment: Thank you very much again and sorry so many questions, but you can explain to me why you have to solve just such a system ?, Where does this system? I noticed that the columns of the matrix $M$ are the elements of the base $B_1$, I can explain why further ?, I not entirely clear, if I want to move from the base $B_1$ to the base $B_2$, do I write the elements of B1 as a linear combination of the elements of $B_2$ or vice versa, the elements of $B_2$ as a linear combination of elements $B_1$?

Comment: Almost I understand, but why do you say you solve that system in the quotient space is equivalent to solve it in $\mathbb{R}^5$? In your explanation you are calculating the transition matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$ or $B_2$ to $B_1$? Sorry for the inconvenience =( and thank you so much for your help!

Comment: no problem with pleasure, the key is that we will understand
everything that happens. Then we have an equation $ f ({\bar x})
= {\bar y} $ to solve in a  quotient $ E / F $,  to solve $ f
(x) = y $ modulo $ F $, so to solve $ f (x) = y + z $ with  $ z \in F $, is that I did.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, in general, when trying to solve a system of equations in the quotient space, it comes from the way you explained in your comment above? What is the theorem for that you describe? Do you know any book or paper that you would recommend to study vector quotient space and its equations?

Comment: welcome, the first must understand what is quotient structure, if
you can read quotient groups and quotient ring this is better,
then  to get rich benefit because vectors space are group abelian
with  external law, else you can work on this paper
http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/qtvector.pdf
and if there questions I am ready to help you, good luck